# Mongoose. Select nested document's _id

Tags: mongoose

My schema looks like the following

```
var child = new Schema({
  some: String
});
var parent = new Schema({
  path: {type: String},
  children: [child]
});
var model = mongoose.model('model', parent);
```

Actually I don't need child schema defined separately. It could be defined within parent as well. The issue remains the same.

So, now i `model.find` the document and expect returned doc to be

```
{
//A lot of mongoose's stuff..
_doc: {
  _id: ObjectId,
  path: 'some string',
  children: [{
      _id:  ObjectId,
      some: 'other string'
    }]
  }
}
```

But the children has no `_id` although when I inspect this document with mongo shell all children have their `_id`s.

The question is how to fetch these `_id`s with the document?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what is going on. 
Deep inside access control layer a function returns all paths that user has access to read. All but `_id`. And `_id` of nested documents are not selected by default unlike primary `_id`s are.